# Tkinter rapid dialog start/end bug

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

Consider the example of the end of this question (it's a ready-to-run Python 3 program):

Anyway, there's a problem with it. That is, if you press the context menu key and the escape key in rapid succession, eventually the keyboard will lock up. Mouse clicks will still work. The only solution seems to be to close the program and restart it.

This may seem like a pretty rare bug, but you actually don't always have to press them so much to cause the bug. Sometimes, with as few as potentially one to three button presses, it locks up. How fast you open and close it seems to matter a great deal. If you take care to press one, wait a moment, and press the other, you'll likely never encounter the bug.

This still may seem like a pretty small problem, since people might not want to open and close it quickly, ever. However, this is just the bare-bones example that produces the problem. It's not my reason for wanting to fix it.

In my actual program (a text editor), you press the menu button (for example; that's not the only use-case), a dialog pops up, you type in something, and it outputs something special to the text editor. It's kind of like a really powerful Linux compose key. I don't want to get into it. You'll just have to trust me that it's exceedingly useful for a variety of purposes.

Anyway, the problem is if people are typing in codes in quick succession, on rare occasions, the keyboard locks up, just as when you alternate pressing escape and the menu button in this example code below. The end_dialog method is called when a successful code is entered. So, the code below is replicating the issue (just without all the functionality).

So, my question is, what is causing the bug? Is something wrong with the code? Is it just my system? I have a suspicion that my video card driver might be the culprit, rather than my code, or Tkinter. So, if you try it for a good while, and still can't replicate the bug, please tell me.

Anyway, I'm using Xubuntu 14.04, 32-bit (Python 3.4.0).

```
from tkinter import *;

class Editor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ckd=None;
        self.tk=Tk();
        self.frame=Frame(self.tk);
        self.text=Text(self.frame);
        self.text.bind("<Menu>", self.my_dialog);
        self.text.pack();
        self.frame.pack();
        self.tk.attributes('-zoomed', True);
        self.text.focus_set();
    def end_dialog(self, event):
        self.text.focus_set();
        self.ckd.destroy();
        self.ckd=None;
        return "break";
    def my_dialog(self, event):
        if self.ckd==None:
            self.ckd=Toplevel(self.tk, height=100, width=200);
            self.ckd.bind("<Escape>", self.end_dialog);
        else:
            #If it is already there, bring it into focus. 
            self.ckd.lift();
            self.text.focus_set();
        return "break";

e=Editor();
e.tk.mainloop();
try:
    e.tk.destroy();
except:
    pass;
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem or not, but I suggest moving the call to mainloop out of the constructor. With it in there, the object never is fully constructed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just tried moving the mainloop outside the class (after `e=Editor();`), but the problem still persisted.

Comment: If I put the dialog and the end dialog methods in a loop in rapid succession (a lot of times), it does not cause the problem. So, as long as they're executed directly one after another, it doesn't seem to cause problems, but then, it doesn't show a visual, either (I don't see anything open and close a thousand times or whatever), and the visual aspects may play a key part in this. I could cause a similar problem if I were using multiple threads. So, I wonder if there might be some code that is accidentally not thread-safe between Windows in the mainloop or something.

Comment: I'll have to test if this only occurs with Toplevel widgets. Also, I added in the mainloop change to the code above.

Comment: Tkinter isn't thread safe, and doesn't use threads itself.Your program doesn't use threads, so it's definitely not thread related.

Comment: Very good to know about Tkinter not using threads. Thanks! I tried a Text widget instead of a Toplevel widget. It doesn't seem to have the same problem. Just to be thorough, Tkinter doesn't use multiprocessing, does it?

Comment: Actually, I take that back. The issue does occur with a Text widget instead of a Toplevel, too.

Comment: Right now, I'm working around it just fine by having a small text widget that is always there in the lower-right corner for stuff like this. I could have it auto-hide after so many seconds of inactivity (so, that way it couldn't be opened and closed rapidly). The issue must have something to do with destroying the object.

Comment: I believe I had a similar issue with withdrawing the Toplevel as I did with destroying it, but it didn't just lock the keyboard. I think it froze the program and sometimes complained about stuff as if it had destroyed the widget and was attempting to access the destroyed version when it seemed it ought to have not been destroyed at that time.

Comment: I changed it so it just lowers and lifts a single Text widget in and out of view without ever destroying it. I change the bindings when it's lowered and lifted. I haven't encountered the issue doing this. So, it looks like I don't need to autohide it. I'll try to keep you posted if I encounter any problems there, but it seems fine.